# Split output in C/C++ for redirecting

Tags: c++, c, stdout, io-redirection, ostream

Suppose I've got code like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Redirect to file1" << endl;
    cout << "Redirect to file2" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to redirect the first output to file1 and the second to file2. Is that possible?

I think in C, `fclose(stdout)` and reopen the `stdout` might help but I'm not sure how to reopen it or whether it works.

Thanks

UPDATE: What for?

I have a program A, which reads input from the user and generates corresponding output. Now I want to check whether it is correct, I have a program B which generate input for A, as well as correct output. B will generate one set of test data at a time. And I will have thousands of tests.

On my machine, a thousand times ``` ./B > ``mktemp a.XXX`` ``` works better than using `ofstream`. Using `fstream` for thousands of times, my hard drive light flashes crazily. But not when redirecting to temp file.

UPDATE2:

In C++, it seems that the prevailing answer is `cout` along with `cerr`.

What about C, apart from `stderr`, can I close `stdout` and reopen it?

Comment: In a POSIX (Linux/OSX/BSD) shell you can redirect `stdout` and `stderr` differently. That's the only way you could do it, by using `std::cout` and `std::cerr`. In a Windows console I don't think it's possible. Also, you can't mix the old C stdio function with C++ streams.

Comment: @Pileborg thanks. is there a way to reopen `stdout` if I `fclose(stdout)`? Say in Linux, can I use `fopen(...)` to reopen `stdout`? And what parameters for it? Thanks

Comment: It's possible, but involves knowing what TTY device it was connected to first, and you probably have to use the `open` system call and then use `fdopen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the **standard error stream** for e.g. error messages.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Redirect to file1" << endl;
    cerr << "Redirect to file2" << endl;
}
```

For example, using the Windows [cmd.exe] command interpreter, and the Visual C++ `cl` compiler:

```
[D:\dev\test]
> type con >streams.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Redirect to file1" << endl;
    cerr << "Redirect to file2" << endl;
}
^Z

[D:\dev\test]
> cl streams.cpp
streams.cpp

[D:\dev\test]
> streams 1>a.txt 2>b.txt

[D:\dev\test]
> type a.txt
Redirect to file1

[D:\dev\test]
> type b.txt
Redirect to file2

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

---

EDIT: added colorized code and boldface emphasis.

Comment: Many thanks, I could just accept one answer =) Please see my update2.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use file streams ? this way it will most likely work regardless of the shell redirection:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
// opeen files
ofstream file1 ( "file1");
ofstream file2 ( "file2");
//write
file1 << "Redirect to file1" << endl;
file2 << "Redirect to file2" << endl;
//close files
file1.close();
file2.close();
```

Comment: Quite complicated to explain. I will update my question to give a backgroud.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cout AND cerr.

```
cout << "Redirect to file1" << endl;
cerr << "Redirect to file2" << endl;
```

cerr goes to standard error

Answer (score 1):

Another way doing it is using `cout.rdbuf()` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    ofstream cfile1("test1.txt");
    ofstream cfile2("test2.txt");

    cout.rdbuf(cfile1.rdbuf());        
    cout << "Redirect to file1" << endl;

    cout.rdbuf(cfile2.rdbuf());        
    cout << "Redirect to file2" << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No `ofstream`. Thousands of `ofstream` in a sequence seems to put a heavy load on my hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Redirect to file1" << endl;
    cerr << "Redirect to file2" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Console:

```
test > 1.txt 2> 2.txt
```

1.txt:

```
Redirect to file1
```

2.txt:

```
Redirect to file2
```

Comment: many thanks, I could only accept one answer=P. Please see my update2 of my question.